# Creating a list in Prolog based on some specifications

Tags: prolog

I am working on a side project in which I am attempting to create a Prolog function that makes a list of atoms, but it must ensure some atoms come before others. Essentially a list of tasks that must be completed however some of the tasks are prerequisites for other tasks.

For example:

```
task(brushteeth).
task(usemouthwash).
task(gotowork).

prereq(usemouthwash, brushteeth).
%where brush teeth must be done prior to using mouthwash
```

I however am having a rough time even creating a list in the first place that can list all of the tasks, let alone having the prerequisites come before other tasks.

Any guidance would be awesome, I am certainly not asking anybody to write this for me I just need a general working example or something to get me started. I have searched an attempted to modify so many things I just can't get anything to work anymore.

Thank you in advance, I a apologies if this question seems vague or unhelpful. I am just really stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start thinking from base cases since you're more likely to write a predicate using recursion:

```
create_list([]). %zero element list is accepted, same for one element below:
create_list([X]):- task(X).
create_list([X,Y|Rest]):- prereq(X,Y), create_list([Y|Rest]).
```

And finally list of fixed length:

```
create_list_len(L,N):- length(L,N), create_list(L).
```

---

Example with facts:

```
task(brushteeth).
task(usemouthwash).
task(gotowork).

prereq(usemouthwash, brushteeth).
prereq(gotowork, usemouthwash).
```

---

```
create_list(L).
L = []
L = [brushteeth]
L = [usemouthwash]
L = [gotowork]
L = [usemouthwash, brushteeth]
L = [gotowork, usemouthwash]
L = [gotowork, usemouthwash, brushteeth]
false

create_list_len(L,3).
L = [gotowork, usemouthwash, brushteeth]
```